# Why does this JQUERY file fail when saved locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have several jquery files that I saved locally with my other site files because I didn't want the page to require code retrieval from remote sites URLs. The process I used to do this was to paste the remote jquery urls into a browser and then copy and paste the code that displays as text in the browser when you do that. I pasted the code into local files that I saved in a sub directory of the site. Named the files with the same name. This worked in all cases but one.

Here is the code that appears in the page when it works.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../client_script/datepicker/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../client_script/datepicker/base.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../client_script/datepicker/base.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../client_script/datemodel/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../client_script/datemodel/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../client_script/datepicker/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../client_script/datepicker/jquery.timepicker.css" />
```

//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

Note how the one include references a remote URL:
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

When I tried to reference the code locally it fails. I get a jscript error on page load that says:

TypeError
Object[object Object] has no method
'datepicker'
(then the file path and line # where i call datepicker)

Is there some logical reason why this particular jquery file won't work when loaded locally? Or is the way I am doing this flawed?

Thanks

Comment: Probably a cache issue. If files on disk and url are both correct, try to bypass browser cache or empty it. By the way // has no meaning there.

Answer (score 0):

When loading the page locally (assuming that you're not also running a server locally) you need to specify the protocol, e.g. `http:`. Otherwise the browser tries to load it with file://...

So

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Will need to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to avoid loading the jquery from a remote url. I need to know why the following doesn't work:  <script type="text/javascript" src="../client_script/datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script> I have saved the contents of jquery-ui.js locally.

Comment: yes - i know the path is good because i have the other files in the same location and they work. something about that particular file doesn't work. i looked to see if there was an indication that that file was dependent on some other asset in the environment of //code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js - but that's not the case. why would the other jquery files work but not this one? mysterious. but i am not a jquery expert, by far - so it wouldn't surprise me to learn that there is something in that file that keeps it from working when removed from the file structure at jquery.com.